# Handle a big list of controls (dynamically remove and create new instance depending of the range view)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dynamic, user-controls, controls

I need to implement a way to handle alot of controls in a panel without busting the capacity and only make one or no  loading if possible.

I would like to have your opinion and your view about my solution and it's feasibility.

Does it possible to make a thread that actually dispose the control that are not in the range view and create new instance of one being in the range.

I'm thinking of a thread because i don't want the UI to be blocked. I just want to "Stream the control".

What is the best way of doing this ??

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have reason to believe your control count is "too many"? I'd ensure you have a problem first.

Comment: Well, we have more than 1000 panels which each contain labels and an heavy object that is tagged. If we go beyond that 1000 instances of controls  we have some wierd issue thats even not related to memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datagridview with virtual mode solve this issue !